# How do you zoom in on a terminal?

Tags: fallout-4

On PC with a Steam controller if that's relevant.

Questions's in the title, really. I can't figure out how to zoom in/out on a terminal. You can change the zoom on the Pip Boy using Back but that didn't do anything when using a terminal. Indeed, I've tried just about everything I can think of and nothing seems to work, zoom level on a terminal seems to be randomly changed.

It only ever seems to change when entering a terminal, I find I've never seen it change when using one.

Nobody else on the internet knows how it works either, I found a handful of Reddit/Steam threads with no definitive answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is why not, and why there isn't even a mod for it.

> I made a mod for this for New Vegas, and it has other features like adjusting IS FOV depending on your settings, as well as pipboy and terminal fov, and a few other things like dialogue and IS zoom time. I was hoping to bring this mod to Fallout 4 eventually, but **looks like a lot of it is done through scaleform which I haven't got the skills to change.**
>
> –[afkmods.iguanadons.net](http://terminal%20zoom%20mod)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can zoom in on a terminal I never have.